# invite Form <fb:request-form action doesn't work?

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, invite

I use the request form for a invite form. But when I send a request to friends the fanpage tab will be blank and the form disappears.

When I delete the "action" entry it works but I will use the action link to add a variable to the Link.
Is this possible like this? action="https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/index.php?invite=1"

My code.

```
<!-- Invite Formular -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">FB.init({appId: 'myappid', status : true, cookie : true, xfbml  : true});</script>

<div id="dialogInviteFriends" style="overflow:hidden; margin-left: -10px;">
<fb:serverfbml  width="520px">
<script type="text/fbml">
<fb:fbml>
<fb:request-form target="_self" method="POST" invite="true" type="Partymaus Salzburg" action="https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/index.php?invite=1" label="Schau jetzt vorbei"
content="Ich hab hier eine super Fanpage gefunden, die musst du dir anschauen.">
<fb:multi-friend-selector actiontext="Sags deinen Freunden" showborder="false"     rows="5" cols="3" import_external_friends = "false">

</fb:request-form>
</fb:fbml>
</script>
</fb:serverFbml>
</div>

<!-- Ende Invite Formular -->
```

Any Help for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to inform you, FBML is being deprecated.  You should change over to using Javascript API's Requests Dialog instead (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

Comment: Correct, the FBML engine is going away very soon.  You will need to recode your solution using the new Javascript SDK's request dialog.

Comment: ok, thanks for this info. But is it possible to create a request for a fanpage? Now when  I send a request, the link which the user can click, take them to the app and not to the fanpage.

Comment: FWIW, I've never setup invites to pages, only invites to apps.   Did you try replacing the appid with the page id?

Comment: Doesn't work. It have solved this problem with a check. So when the user comes to the Apppage, he will get redirected to the fanpage.